# sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier: which is the optmized Cart algorithm implementation?

Tags: python, algorithm, decision-tree

according to the online sklearn documentation (v0.14), the growth of a tree classifier is done via an "optimized version of the CART algorithm". Do someone know the details about such implementation? I'm writing an homemade Cart training algorithm, and my version is at best 20 times slower given the same input.

Thank you for sharing any information

Pietro

Comment: Have you looked at the repo on github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L334

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, from the [comments in the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L334), it is the CART algorithm with some added features borrowed from classics from the litterature:

- L. Breiman, J. Friedman, R. Olshen, and C. Stone, "Classification and
  Regression Trees", Wadsworth, Belmont, CA, 1984.
- T. Hastie, R. Tibshirani and J. Friedman. "Elements of Statistical
  Learning", Springer, 2009.
- L. Breiman, and A. Cutler, "Random Forests",
  http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm